# How to implement browser-friendly SSL/HTTPS without a domain name?

Tags: ssl, https

I have a backend application that creates temporary servers via the Digital Ocean API. There is a browser frontend that needs to send AJAX requests to the servers.

Let's Encrypt isn't an option because they require a domain name, like most SSL certificate providers. I could create my own self-signed certificate, but then the browser would not trust it.

Although I could probably assign a subdomain to each temporary server, it may take some time for the DNS to recognize the assignment.

Is there a solution for secure and browser-accepted communication to my temporary servers?

Comment: While technically you can have IP-based X.509 certificates, this does not mix well with HTTPS. Indeed you should instead: "Although I could probably assign a subdomain to each temporary server,", because "it may take some time for the DNS to recognize the assignment." is not necessarily true, you can just have a TTL of 5 minutes for your subdomain and with a wildcard X509 certificate you have only one to maintain.

Comment: Yes, it seems that using a domain/subdomain is the only way to go. Thanks for the comment.